# what is the worth of non-read once Branching Programs?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs

In [Harvard CS 221 Computational Complexity, Lecture 3](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/%7Emadhusudan/courses/Spring2018/scribe/lect03.pdf), it introduced **Branching Programs**

> A branching program is a DAG that
> has 1 start node and 2 output nodes with out-degree 0, labelled 0 and 1. Each non-output
> node is labeled with one of x1, x2, . . . , xn and each node has 2 outgoing edges labeled 0 and 1

For example

> [image: an example of branching programs]

There is a derived defination of **read-once BranchingPrograms**

> the read-once restriction, where
> a read-once BP reads each input value at most once in any computation path

**My question**: Obviously every *Branching Programs* can transform to *read-once type*, so what is the worth of *non-read once Branching Programs*?